# Why does the same const struct as match guard compile but not as match pattern?

Tags: rust

I was struggling a bit to handle errors from the `postgres` crate. Specifically, the `SqlState` in `postgres::error`. Since the constants are using `Cow`, I did not manage to use it in a simple way in match patterns.

For example, `UNIQUE_VIOLATION` is defined as

```
/// 23505
pub const UNIQUE_VIOLATION: SqlState = SqlState(Cow::Borrowed("23505"));
```

I ended up with doing the following, but I am sure there is a more ergonomic/canonical way of matching the errors.

```
        let maybe_user: postgres::Result<User> = create_user(&conn, email);
        match maybe_user {
            Err(e) => {
                // e.code() returns Option<&postgres::SqlState>
                match e.code() {
                    None => panic!("not a sql error"),
                    Some(sqlstate) if sqlstate == &UNIQUE_VIOLATION => {
                        // do something...
                    },
                    Some(sqlstate) => panic!("unexpected error"),
                }
            }
            Ok(user) => {
                assert_eq!(user.email, email);
            }
        }
```

If I want to explicitly handle a large quantity of errors, it gets really tedious to repeat lines like

```
Some(sqlstate) if sqlstate == &UNIQUE_VIOLATION => {},
```

So, my question is, is there a simpler, more ergonomic way of matching on these errors?

## Update: What I tried

The suggestion of @edwardw is what I wanted to achieve but everything I tried did not compile.

1. Using `UNIQUE_VIOLATION` in the match pattern gives the error:

```
expected &postgres_shared::error::sqlstate::SqlState, found struct postgres_shared::error::sqlstate::SqlState
```

2. Using `&UNIQUE_VIOLATION` in the match patterns gives the error:

```
error: to use a constant of type std::borrow::Cow in a pattern, std::borrow::Cow must be annotated with #[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
```

## Update 2: Minimal Example

Heres a minimal example to quickly reproduce the errors:

```
use postgres::error::UNIQUE_VIOLATION;
use postgres::Result;

fn example() {
    let sql_state = &UNIQUE_VIOLATION;

    match sql_state {
        // this match arm works
        s if s == &UNIQUE_VIOLATION => {
            // do something...
        }
        // this match arm does not compile
        &UNIQUE_VIOLATION => {},
        _ => panic!("unexpected state"),
    }
}
```

Requires `postgres` as dependency in `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
postgres = "0.15.2"
```

Comment: Actually better please do a [mcve]

Comment: @Stargateur added minimal example

Comment: you first talk about a design problem than you give a compile error problem please keep your original answer don't continue/modify an question because there is an answer. Choice.

Comment: I did not change the question. It is exactly the same. I only specified more clearly the challenges of coming up with a nicer solution for matching the errors. Also I added the minimal example without changing anything else, since that was a valid criticism of my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm afraid that you can't do much better than this. One "obvious" improvement seems to be:

```rust
match e.code().expect("not a sql error") {
    &UNIQUE_VIOLATION => {
        // do something
    },
    _ => panic!("unexpected error"),
}
```

But it fails to compile with the error:

> error: to use a constant of type `std::borrow::Cow` in a pattern, `std::borrow::Cow` must be annotated with `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]`

The reason why it should fail isn't obvious. The Rust reference has this [passing sentence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#path-patterns):

> (...in a path patterns...) Struct and enum constants must have `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]` (not merely implemented).

Turns out this is deliberate on the part of `rustc`. [RFC 1445](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1445-restrict-constants-in-patterns.md) explains why and how. In short,

> When expanding constants of struct or enum type into equivalent patterns, require that the struct or enum type is decorated with `#[structural_match]`.

The feature gate `#[structural_match]` will be kept unstable. This feature gate is only automatically applied if a struct or enum is marked as `#[derive(Eq)]` but not if manually implemented. The `std::borrow::Cow` struct, which is part of `SqlState` you tried to match against, unfortunately falls into later category.

The `==` operator, however, is not subject to such restriction. So a constant struct or enum can still be used in match guards as you did in the question.

Comment: True, using expect makes it more concise. The matching doesn't work though. `code` returns a reference to `SqlState`:

```
expected `&postgres_shared::error::sqlstate::SqlState`, found struct `postgres_shared::error::sqlstate::SqlState`
```

When I try to match on a reference `&UNIQUE_VIOLATION`, I get this:

```
error: to use a constant of type `std::borrow::Cow` in a pattern, `std::borrow::Cow` must be annotated with `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]`
```

Comment: cool, thanks for the explanation. I was stuck and didn't find any good explanations. It is a pity though that the errors have to be handled in such a cumbersome way.